# if more then one line have same string, remove all the lines except first using unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a input as

```
Client=abc
Operation=123
Client=bcd
Operation=234
Operation=345
Operations=567
Client=def
Operation=789
Operation=892
Client=efg
Operation=991
```

I am expecting output as

```
Client=abc
Operation=123
Client=bcd
Operation=234
Client=def
Operation=789
Client=efg
Operation=991
```

If there is a string match in consecutive lines then all matching lines except the first once should be deleted.
I've tried awk '$1!=p{print;p=$1}' fileName, but not of any help.

Comment: This can be done in awk.  Set the delim to "=".  Store $1 in a var called previous.  If $1 == previous don't print.  If $1 != previous then print and set previous to $1.

Comment: Why isn't the `Operations=567` line selected since the key is different from the `Operation=123` line?

Comment: awk '$1!=p{print;p=$1}' it worked. The problem was delimited "=", Once I replaced it with space it executed fine.
sed 's/\=/ /g' |awk '$1!=p{print;p=$1}'

Comment: Hi Johathan,
This is output of a log file, since client of Operation=345 and Operations=567 is not present in the log file, hence they should be removed.

Comment: OK; so it is 'client line + first following line, assuming the next line is not another client line'.  If you got successive lines with 'Client=xxx' (for different values of xxx, presumably), you'd only want to see the second client?  Or would you want to see all the client lines without exception?  And presumably, if the first lines are not client lines, you don't want to see them either?

Comment: I would like to see operation only if their is a relative Client for it.

Comment: Did you try re-running your awk with the addition of -F"="?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F= '$1=="Client"{op=0} !op{print} $1=="Operation"{op=1}' file
Client=abc
Operation=123
Client=bcd
Operation=234
Client=def
Operation=789
Client=efg
Operation=991
```

**Explanation:**

1. `-F=` sets input field separator as `=`
2. Set a variable `op` to `0` when we get a line with `Client`
3. If `op` is `0` then print record thus printing `Client=` and first `Operation=` lines
4. When we get first `Operation=` line we set `op` = `1`

Comment: If an 'operation' precedes the first client line, does it get printed anyway?  Should it?  Does inverting the sense of `op` and using `op == 1 { print }` do the trick (or an abbreviated version of `op == 1`).

Comment: I think OP needs to clarify if `Operation` line can also come before `Client` line

Answer (score -1):

What you have looks fine maybe you just need to set the delim to "=".

```
awk -F"="
```

EDIT:  Tested the OP's script but added -F"="

```
awk -F"=" '$1!=p{print;p=$1}' fileName
```

and got the output:

```
Client=abc
Operation=123
Client=bcd
Operation=234
Operations=567
Client=def
Operation=789
Client=efg
Operation=991
```

Notice how the third Operation is there when one would think it should be gone.  The OP's input had Operation and Operations... notice the 's' in the end.  Because of that 's' the script separates Operation from Operations... which I think is correct logic.  Maybe the 's' was added by OP by mistake.  It you remove that 's' then you get the output:

```
Client=abc
Operation=123
Client=bcd
Operation=234
Client=def
Operation=789
Client=efg
Operation=991
```